# extjs tooltip get cell index

Tags: extjs, grid, tooltip

I'm using this code to show a custom tooltip on every row of a grid. The problem is that I have to show it only on some columns. How can I retrieve cellIndex in the beforeshow event?
I've tried with tipp.triggerElement.cellIndex and tipp.anchorElement.cellIndex but I get undefined

```
var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
  // The overall target element.
  target: grid.el,
  // Each grid row causes its own separate show and hide.
  delegate: grid.view.cellSelector,
  // Moving within the row should not hide the tip.
  trackMouse: true,
  // Render immediately so that tip.body can be referenced prior to the first show.
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  listeners: {
      // Change content dynamically depending on which element triggered the show.
      beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tipp) {            
      }
  }
```

});

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    listeners:{
        render:function(grid) {
            var view=grid.getView();
            view.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                target: grid.el,
                // this gets css query to identify the individual cells
                delegate: view.cellSelector,
                listeners: {
                    beforeshow: function(tip) {
                        var column = view.getGridColumns()[tip.triggerElement.cellIndex];
                        var record = view.getRecord(tip.triggerElement.parentNode);
                        tip.update(record.get(column.dataIndex));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I've already tried it but I get that tip.triggerElement.cellIndex is undefined

Comment: Ok, I had to add `selType: 'cellmodel'`to the grid and now it works. Thanks to you and @surya-prakash-tumma

Answer (score 2):

First put a config on your grid `selType: 'cellmodel',` by doing this you can get current postion of selected cell using the below code.

`grid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition();`

which will retruns the current row and column details and some other details as well, so you need access this data in before show event of tip and you return false you no need to show it.

Comment: I get undefined, can you please link me where did you find the getCurrentPosition method? I can't find it in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model)

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.selection.CellModel-method-getCurrentPosition. if it Ext js 5 or above go with getPosition method

Answer (score 1):

When I want (onmouseover) to display in a tooltip the contents of a cell/column (for example, the content is longer than the width of the cell) I use the following renderer method that you mabe can adapt to your case with the value you want:

```
 renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
           metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip= "' + value + '" data-qclass="tipCls" ';
           return value;
 }
```

Works fine in my cases and is simple.

Take a look at: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179016-Grid-cell-tooltip

Comment: I've tried it but my tooltip is html formatted [like this](http://i.imgur.com/gZPElqc.jpg) and I was not able to get the same result with the renderer function. I think that it doesn't accept html and css tags in data-qtip attribute

Comment: Take a look at first Callout Tip: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/qtips/qtips.html

Comment: And this (sword-it answer; copy is code to fiddle): https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?226358-How-to-add-a-template-to-tooltip